# Rewrite regex without '\K'

Tags: java, regex

I have a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/X5r22W/1) that receives html tags without a tag name:

```
<(\s)*\w* \K.*>
```

But `Java`  doesn't support `\K` into regex

I'm [trying to rewrite](https://regex101.com/r/DASNUS/2) without `\K`, but for me it seems impossible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the tag's name is unknown, so look-behind cannot be used. Hence, you'll have to use the matching groups in order to analyze your input.

[The following regex](https://regex101.com/r/J2q7ud/1) will match two groups:

```
(?:<\s*\w+\s+)(.+)(?=>)
```

Group #0 will include the `<` in its beginning, while group #1 will contain only the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

A simple workaround would be to wrap everything after `\K` in a group. Then, when you get group 1, it's *as if* you are getting group 0 using the original regex with `\K`.

```
<(\s)*\w* (.*>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/X5r22W/2)